# Twitter Bootstrap: Want the alerts not moving the rest of the page down

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

So say in my user sign up (using Devise), I've got the error messages at the very top of the sign up page.

```
<% if @user.errors.any? %>
  <div class="alert alert-error">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
    <%= devise_error_messages! %>
  </div>
<% end %>

<div><%= f.label :email %><br />
<%= f.email_field :email %></div>

<div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
```

However, when I put nothing in, attempt to sign up and get the error, the rest of the page will move down. I'm trying to get the error to just appear above the page, and then have the form so I can close it and have nothing there (none of the page moves when I close).

For instance at Twitter.com, attempting to sign in with no information, Twitter will ask if you're human in a black popup box that doesn't move the page down.

I'm at a loss on how to get bootstrap to do this.

What I'm speaking of, is this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZPpk.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually found the best way to do this.

First, download the files at [Nijikokun's bootstrap-notify](https://github.com/Nijikokun/bootstrap-notify) and place them into your project.

Then, add the snippet of code that will show your flash at the bottom of your application.html.haml file (what I use, maybe it's .html.erb). Mine looks like (in HAML):

```
- flash.each do |key, value|
  .notifications.top-center
    %div{class: "alert alert-#{key} in fade"}
      %button.close{"data-dismiss" => "alert", type: "button"} &times;
      -if value.is_a?(String)
        = value
      -else
        -if value.nil?
          = devise_error_messages
        -else
          - value.each do |msg|
            %li
              = msg
```

Basically, what this will do, is go through it and check to see if there is anything other than just a regular string. If it's just **a** string (meaning, it's not an array of strings), post it. Then, if it's not a string, you need to check if it's nil, which if it is it will be the devise error messages (if you have devise). If you don't have devise or don't want the devise error messages, just skip the `- if value.nil?` part and go to what each of the array's values are and post them out with everything from `- value.each do |msg|` and beyond.

Now, if you want it to appear on the top-center (like what mine currently does), you need to add this to the bootstrap-notify's CSS file: `.notifications.top-center{top:40px;left:0;width:100%;}.notifications.top-center>div{margin:5px auto;width:20%;text-align:center;}`

After that, it should work like the way I wanted above!

Answer (score 9):

Twitter has a div with `position: fixed;` which does the trick for them, and then they have a div with the `message` class inside the div with the `alert-messages` class.

```
.alert-messages {
  position: fixed;
  top: 47px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  z-index: 7000;
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I meant. I'm pretty sure it's jQuery that's what i want. It basically will show up but it doesn't affect the web page at all (it's its own). And when you close it, the website isn't altered at all.

For instance, this: http://i.imgur.com/UUYLkax.jpg

Comment: I copied that CSS snippet straight from the source of Twitter, so it's definitely the way they are doing it. When you set a div to `position: fixed` it should not alter the position of other elements of the website at all when you close the alert using the [Bootstrap Alert plugin](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/javascript.html#alerts), is that what you mean by wanting jQuery?

Answer (score 4):

Try using a modal:  http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

```
<!-- Button to trigger modal -->
<a href="#myModal" role="button" class="btn" data-toggle="modal">Launch demo modal</a>

<!-- Modal -->
<div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <p>One fine body…</p>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div>
```